# OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x34363268/'h264' is not supported with codec

Tags: python, macos, opencv, ffmpeg, h.264

After installed opencv like on Mac OS 10.13.6:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

And using `fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('h', '2', '6', '4')` in videowriter

I get error:

```
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x34363268/'h264' is not supported with codec id 27 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x31637661/'avc1'
```

How to fix it?

Comment: As far as I know you need libx264 to encode h264, by default you can only decode that format. I'm not sure if installing libx264 would fix your issue though.

Comment: If OpenCV is using ffmpeg to write, then avc1 is the correct tag for h264 in mp4

Answer (score 4):

You should change:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('h', '2', '6', '4')
```

to:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'avc1')
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libx264-dev` did not work for me

Comment: since this was not clear to me i thought of putting it here for reference... `avc1` actually is `h264` (from wikipedia: "Advanced Video Coding (AVC), also referred to as H.264..." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding)

Answer (score 4):

The codecs are platform dependent, that could be the problem. Try using this combination:

- extension of file = `test.mkv`
- codec . = `CV_FOURCC(*'X264)`

Here is the reference [link](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html)

Comment: This worked perfect. Thanks.  @mrgloom accept this answer so that it can be helpful to others also.

Answer (score 2):

First like some answers pointed out, we should use "AVC1" instead of "h264".
Secondly, when we are using opencv-python, there are some licence issues : https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/207 , we may need to compile on our own.

Answer (score 1):

FourCC is a 4-byte code used to specify the video codec. The list of available codes can be found in fourcc.org. It is platform dependent. The following codecs work fine for me.

- In Fedora: DIVX, XVID, MJPG, X264, WMV1, WMV2. (XVID is more
  preferable. MJPG results in high size video. X264 gives very small
  size video)
- In Windows: DIVX (More to be tested and added)
- In OSX: MJPG (.mp4), DIVX (.avi), X264 (.mkv).

[Source](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html)

Comment: fourcc.org currently points to an irrelevant business site. (2022)