# Save video in opencv with H264 codec

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am using `opencv-python==4.5.1.48` and `python3.9` docker. I want to save a video in h264 format. Here is my function to save a video:

```
import cv2

def save_video(frames):
    fps = 30
    video_path = '/home/save_test.mp4'
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'h264')
    video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(video_path, fourcc, fps, (112, 112))

    for frame in frames:
        video_writer.write(frame)

    video_writer.release()
```

When I use .mp4 format to save video, I get the following error:

> OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x34363268/'h264' is not supported with codec id
> 27 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)' OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to
> use tag 0x31637661/'avc1' Could not find encoder for codec id 27:
> Encoder not found

I search and read some solutions but none of them solve my issue.

**Update**:

I also install `libx264-dev` which was recommended in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52932157/opencv-ffmpeg-tag-0x34363268-h264-is-not-supported-with-codec/56723380) and did not work.

Comment: use `avc1` fourcc -- opencv probably uses its own ffmpeg, so what you install in your system won't matter

Comment: Thanks. I change the `h264` to `avc1` and get this error: `Could not find encoder for codec id 27: Encoder not found`

Comment: since that didn't help, I guess you can't use H.264 https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/207 or you have to build OpenCV yourself, or find a package that disregards the GPL -- use a different codec. `MJPG` always works because it's built into OpenCV. or `mp4v`, that's the predecessor of H.264.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. I can solve my problem in the `ubuntu:20.04` docker. The important thing you should notice is that you should install OpenCV via `apt-get install python3-opencv` not using `pip`.

Comment: Tried installing python3-opencv on ubuntu:20.04 but no luck. Could you please share your dockerfile?

OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x34363268/'h264' is not supported with codec id 27 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x31637661/'avc1'
[ERROR:0@1.556] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp (2767) open Could not find encoder for codec_id=27, error: Encoder not found
[ERROR:0@1.556] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp (2839) open VIDEOIO/FFMPEG: Failed to initialize VideoWriter

Comment: I also install these ubuntu packages: RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \ 
    wget \
    build-essential \
    pkg-config \
    cmake \
    ninja-build \
    libgl1-mesa-glx \
    libleptonica-dev \
    ffmpeg \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libncurses5-dev \
    libgdbm-dev \
    libnss3-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libreadline-dev \
    libffi-dev \
    python3.8 \
    python3-pip \
    python3-opencv  @y2kbug

Comment: I am still getting the same error message. May you take a look on my dockerfile please? https://pastebin.com/RvCK0YBR (btw why tagging username does not work)

Comment: @y2kbug Ok. I will check your DockerFile with my python sample code and inform the result to you.

Comment: @y2kbug I test it. When I do install OpenCV with pip it works. In your dockerfile you install OpenCV with pip.

Comment: Should it be `apt-get install python3-opencv`, `pip3 install opencv-python` or both?

Comment: @y2kbug You should install OpenCV only by this `apt-get install python3-opencv`.

Comment: This is the new dockerfile https://pastebin.com/Hzeey5qD and I am still getting the error https://pastebin.com/SU8xYQFt

Comment: I have tried building OpenCV https://pastebin.com/CizysgwJ During build it can detect FFMpeg https://pastebin.com/JmUZ5x1L FFMpeg should support H264 encoding. No idea why OpenCV still cannot encode with H264

Comment: I do not mean that. You can download my Dockerfile from this link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zItn2Vu5rUPRJXhr9ETM8RRHwn0pdknO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Same error using your dockerfile. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @y2kbug Can you share your code for saving video?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/SU8xYQFt

Comment: MP4V works for my needs. I am giving H264 / H265 / X264 / X265. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Below is my solution on ubuntu20.04：

```
sudo apt install build-essential cmake git python3-dev python3-numpy \
libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev \
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev \
libgstreamer1.0-dev libgtk-3-dev \
libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libopenexr-dev libtiff-dev libwebp-dev \
libopencv-dev x264 libx264-dev libssl-dev ffmpeg


python -m pip install --no-binary opencv-python opencv-python
```

[refer](https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/299)

Answer (score 2):

you can either build opencv by yourself(as mentioned above) or do a quicker solution: install anaconda3 and after creating a new environment run "conda install -c conda-forge opencv"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am saving an MP4 video. Changing `fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'avc1')` into `fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')` solves this issue.