# Very low fps and frame drop in screen recording?

Tags: python, screen-recording

Hi guys i'm building a screen recorder, it works and it creates the "output" video of the screen recording but there is one problem, when i run the program i notice a lot of frame drops when i drag and move a window for example, and in the final file, the video output, the FPS are not right i mean there are lags every time i move a window when i watch the final video, i tried to change the "fps" value of the program but the frame drops still remain, i have a monitor with 1920x1080 resolution with 120 fps so it's very smooth, how to solve this in order to have a fluid output video? Thanks a lot

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from  PIL import ImageGrab
def screenRec():
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
    fps = 8.0
    out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.mp4",fourcc,fps,(1920,1080))
    while (True):
        img = ImageGrab.grab()
        img_np = np.array(img)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        out.write(frame)
screenRec()
```

Answer (score 0):

What about trying DivX MPEG-4 codification?

Replace this line

```
 fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
```

With

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"DIVX")
```

Another codecs you could try are MP4v (H264 predecessor) and H264/H265 encoding (for this buds you'll have to manually build the OpenCV library which steps are described [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python#manual-builds)

Some of the information is extracted from this post [Save video in opencv with H264 codec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70247344/save-video-in-opencv-with-h264-codec)

This new one gives you more fps and has a sinchronization with waitKey of 0.05 before printing the frame.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from  PIL import ImageGrab
def screenRec():
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
    fps = 20
    out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.mp4",fourcc,fps,(1920,1080))
    while (True):
        img = ImageGrab.grab()
        img_np = np.array(img)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        out.write(frame)
        cv2.waitKey(50)
screenRec()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, i tried with you codecs but is the same result, it seems more a problem with fps more than a codec problem, any other solutions for the terrrible low fps?

Comment: read my update from the answer box, hope this time it was useful.

Comment: I tried but it seems the same result again, 20 fps i think are too much  because the video is super fast, speeded up and still frame drops, maybe it should be a complete different program